# How to remove brackets from JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using `json.dumps` to load lists of dictionaries into a JSON object.  My output resembles this:

```
[
    {
        "MetaData": {},
        "SRData": {
            "ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval": {
                "DeadAnimalRemoval": [
                    {
                        "DACItemCount": "0",
                        "DACType": " ",
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar",
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1",
                        "Name": "070920151119458601",
                        "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                    },
                    {
                        "DACType": " ",
                        "DriverFirstName": "SA",
                        "DriverLastName": "Aguilar",
                        "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1",
                        "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ReasonCode": "",
            "ResolutionCode": "A",
            "SRNumber": "1-20979881"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I successfully remove the brackets at the beginning and end of the JSON object?

Code that appends dictionaries and lists:

```
    dL311 = dict()
    dL311.setdefault("DeadAnimalRemoval", l311)
    dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval",dL311)

    #Ends of adding additional itmes ****************************************
    lResults.append({"MetaData": {}, "SRData": dResult})

    ii = ii + 1
    print(json.dumps(lResults, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Comment: You may not really want to do the because it may force other code that deals with the result have to check whether it is a list or dictionary (or assume it's one or the other and use `try/except` in handle the situation when the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: You don't just "remove brackets", you need to recognize what exactly they represent. Your json represents an array of objects. To think of it any other way is just downright wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just serialize the dictionary:

```
result = {"MetaData": {}, "SRData": dResult}
print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 4):

The brackets denote a JSON array, containing one element in your example. In Python, simply pick out the first element of the root array and convert back to JSON.

```
import json
data = json.loads('[...]')
str = json.dumps(data[0])
```